# Shell Script Variable Manipulation

Tags: string, shell, variables, loops

I've got this script:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    q=${f#*Media/Music/}
    echo q
done
```

All I want to do is set `q` to `f` after `Media/Music/`.

But it just echoes nothing.

If I do `echo "${f#*Media/Music/}"` then it gives me my result.

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

You should use $ or ${} to get a variable.

```
for f in "$@"
do
    q=${f#*Media/Music/}
    echo $q   # here use $q it'll work fine.
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add $ for printing the variable.It is printing nothing because by default the value of a variable is initialized to NULL. You need to use

```
echo $q
```

instead of

```
echo q
```